# HDMI output is off once I connected my pi to an oscillscope

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, rpi.gpio, rpio

I connected the +5v and gnd of my raspberry pi to an oscilloscope. Once I did that, my screen gave me a blank screen as if it is not getting any output from HDMI of raspberry pi. I turned off/on the board. The ACT LED will flash; the LAN LED also flashes. However, I no longer get any video signal. What did I do wrong? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible that you may have shorted the GPIO pins?

Comment: Have you tried a different sd card?

Comment: yes I tried with a different SD card. No luck. @Mohammad Ali

Comment: Which 5v and ground did you connect? Do you mean the gpio pins or the test points?

Comment: I am using a ADC DAC pi zero. I connected to the +5, gnd on that board. it has this schematics https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/docs/stock/raspberrypi/adcdacpizero/adcdacpizero-schematic.pdf @Mohammad Ali

Comment: It doesn't have a 5v in the diagram but it wouldn't matter your Pi is likely dead